# Get the summation of values at column level in a text file using shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk

My query is simple to get the summation of values at column level in a text file using shell -- i.e. to add a new record in the text file which includes the sum.

For example here below:

```
name usersToday usersTommorrow    
Data1 92 181    
DataTwo 5 7    
Something 61 73    
Something_with_long_name 0 0
```

the desired output is

```
name usersToday usersTommorrow    
Data1 92 181   
DataTwo 5 7    
Something 61 73  
Something_with_long_name 0 0
Total 158 262
```

Please note that the text file will be updated with a new data column periodically everyday.

so on day 2 - post the commands for summation are updated the file will be like

```
name usersToday day2
Data1 92 181    
DataTwo 5 7    
Something 61 73    
Something_with_long_name 0 0
Total 158 262
```

On day 3 - post new data is appended the file will be like

```
name usersToday day2 day3
Data1 92 181 52
DataTwo 5 7 53
Something 61 73 25    
Something_with_long_name 0 0 26
Total 158 262
```

so I want the summation for day3 needs to be updated.

Comment: Youre expected to include your code. We'll help you fix it, but we won't write it for you. Please read [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) and [Help On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before asking more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that your actual Input_file will be same as shown samples, could you please try following then.

```
awk 'FNR>1 && NF{first+=$2;second+=$3} 1; END{print "Total "first,second}' Input_file
```

Comment: the file will be updated daily - with a new column being added everyday, so I will need to have summation of all including new column - probably summate everyday post data is appended.

Comment: @dynamicJos, need to take care of it, will check on it once.

Comment: @dynamicJos, do you need daily new total? or keep updating totals like `total` for today, `total1` for yesterday etc etc in same file?

Comment: need to keep updating the total everyday (only for the new day and not do anything to the existing already summed up total of previous days)

Comment: @dynamicJos, not sure if I got it correctly, could you please show samples in your post once and let me know then?

Comment: Updated the scenario in question